# ssh-ing to remote machine connects me back to local machine?

Tags: ssh, networking, multiple-machines

I have two computers: my laptop, `vagrant`, and my desktop tower, `frontier`. My username for both is `joseph`. I can `ssh` just fine from `frontier` to `vagrant`, but I have never been able to do it the other way around. I also have not been able to figure out why. I tried every solution I could find, like restarting `sshd`, reinstalling `ssh-daemon`, even just reinstalling the OS, and more. No luck.

Today, I try it again, and it appears to work. However, it just connects me back to my laptop!

Running `ssh -v joseph@frontier` from my laptop gives me this (some information redacted to avoid revealing personal information):

```
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to frontier [IP-address] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/joseph/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/joseph/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/joseph/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/joseph/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/joseph/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/joseph/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/joseph/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/joseph/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.6 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA
[redacted]
debug1: Host 'frontier' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/joseph/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: [private-key: redacted]
debug1: Trying private key: [private-key: redacted]
debug1: Trying private key: [private-key: redacted]
debug1: Trying private key: [private-key: redacted]
debug1: Next authentication method: password
joseph@frontier's password:
```

Entering my password logs me into a prompt, which is on my local machine!! As in I have somehow `ssh-ed` from my laptop back to my laptop!

This is not making any sense to me. My last attempt to fix this (on my own) resulted in me accidentally bricking my desktop OS.

I am running Linux Mint 17.1 on my laptop and the latest version of Manjaro on my desktop tower. I have never encountered anything like this.

If there is any other information I can provide, please comment it below and I will get it up ASAP.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In this line: `debug1: Connecting to frontier [IP-address] port 22.` is `IP-address` an IP local to your host? ssh doesn't do anything fancy-- it connects to the IP that the name resolution process provides. Plus since the host key matches, you've been there before...

Comment: @SteveBonds interesting question--one of the first things I did was check to see what the IP was. `nslookup` doesn't return anything useful, but when I ping it it is up. `ssh`ing to that address specifically just takes me back to the laptop. When I run `ifconfig` on my tower and `ssh` to the IP there, it tells me the connection is refused.

Comment: Sounds like you have a name resolution mess to sort out and either sshd isn't running on `frontier` or your firewall is blocking port 22.

Comment: @SteveBonds I have fixed firewall problems before; I will attempt that now. However, could you be more specific when you say "name" mess? Running `uname -a` on both machines yields the correct, respective names.

Comment: In order to reach a host by name, it must first be converted to an IP address. Perhaps this will help clarify this and some some of the other basics of TCP/IP: [Penguintutor Basic Network Reference](http://www.penguintutor.com/linux/basic-network-reference)

Comment: @SteveBonds cool! thanks for taking the time to explain this to me, it has been bamboozling me for days.

Comment: @SteveBonds wrote _"ssh doesn't do anything fancy-- it connects to the IP that the name resolution process provides"_, but there is something 'fancy' done by SSH - if you have a `Host` entry matching the supplied name in your `~/.ssh/config` (or, horrors, in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`), then it may have a `HostName` stanza redirecting to a different hostname or IP address (yes, this can be useful!).  So check your config files (or avoid them by passing `-F /dev/null`).

Comment: Hi @JosephFarah you mentioned that you are also geting _connection is refused_ error when you are trying to connect to your desktop machine. Are you sure that open ssh server is listening on 22 port on your desktop machine. Can you please post the output of command **netstat -ntlp** from your desktop.

Comment: @GauravPundir that would seem likely. Editing question to include the command output. Do you want me to be root?

Comment: In order for the `-p` option on `netstat` to work properly, you would need to be root. If you don't want to be root, you can infer that `sshd` is running by seeing this output as non-root: `tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      -` (port 22 listening on 0.0.0.0)